# styled ul within another styled ul

Tags: html, css

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/dalal/e3BHm/  this shows what i'm talking about.. please check it out..

I have a styled list within another styled list.. I don't want the second list to inherit the first list's styles, but it does!!
here's an example of what I've got in style sheet file:

```
    .tabs
{
    position:relative;
    text-align:left; /* This is only if you want the tab items at the center */        
    width: 90%;   
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/

}
.tabs ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block; /* Change this to block or inline for non-center alignment */
    width:570px;  
    /*  min-width:570px;  
      max-width:800px;     
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
.tabs ul ul.mm
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block; /* Change this to block or inline for non-center alignment */

    /*  min-width:570px;  
      max-width:800px;     
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
.tabs ul  li
{
    display:inline;
    float:center;
    vertical-align: bottom;   
   /** border: 1px solid yellow;*/  
    cursor:hand; 

}
.tabs ul ul.mm li.oo
{
    display:block;
    float:center;
    vertical-align: bottom;   
   /** border: 1px solid yellow;*/  
    cursor:hand; 

}
.tabs ul li  a
{
    color:#7a7883;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #f1f3f4;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;  
    width: 25%;  

    font-size:15px;   
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;

    border-top-left-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius-topleft:4px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius-topright:4px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    cursor:hand;    
      /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */ background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#aeb8c0));
    /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */ background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aeb8c0, #fff);  /* Firefox 3.6+ */   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aeb8c0, #fff);
    /* IE 10 */ background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #aeb8c0, #fff);  /* Opera 11.10+ */  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aeb8c0, #fff);    
}
.tabs ul ul.mm li.oo  a
{
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;  
    width: 25%;  

    font-size:15px;   
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.tabs ul li  a:hover
{

    color: #fff;   
    cursor:hand; 

}

.tabs ul li  div
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
     width:98%;  
    /* max-width:700px;*/ 
     min-height:230px;
    left:0; 
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    z-index:-1;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;  
}
.tabs ul li  div  p
{
    border:1px solid #f1f3f4;      
    background-color: #f5f9fc;  
    width: 99%;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;  
    color: #65636e;
    font-size:12px;   
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-decoration: none;       
    min-height:200px;

}
.tabs ul li  a:focus
{  
    color: #f5f9fc;  

}

.tabs ul li:target  a
{
    cursor:default;
         /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f1f3f4), to(#fff));

  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f1f3f4);

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f1f3f4);

  /* IE 10 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f1f3f4);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f1f3f4);   
    cursor:hand; 
}

.tabs ul li:target  div
{
    display:block;
}
```

and here's the code inside the page:

```
<div class="t" >
      <ul class="menu">
        <li id="item-1"   >
          <a href="#item-1">First Main List</a>
           <div style="display:block" class="myList" id="#item-1">
            <p> 
                <ul class="m">           
                  <li><a href="">second list</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">second list</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">second list</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">second list</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="item-2">   .......
        </li>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the second list doesn't appear in the style I made for them.. plus, the second list displayed after the block of the `<p>` not inside of it.

thank you in advance :)

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and if you change the color for `.myList ul.m li > a` it does in fact change. What exactly is getting inherited that you don't want inherited?

Comment: I didn't put the entire code to keep viewers from reading long topic.. the colors I tested change perfectly.. but I have borders on the first list don't want them to be inherited to the second one.. I'll add the whole code.. thank you for responding..

Comment: would you please check this one http://jsfiddle.net/dalal/e3BHm/  @JasonM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgot `>` on lines 17 and 39 of your CSS...

as in this:
`.t ul.menu li > a` should actually be `.t ul.menu > li > a`.

also note that you picked the same color for the first list and the second list.. `#7a7883`. just for testing - I commented out the color of the second list for you to see it does not inherit

Check this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jn3hX/1/)

Comment: I tried it with '>' and without it.. and it doesn't make any difference.. thank you for responding..

Comment: I can't figure out what are the inherited attributes you're talking about.. in my fiddle you can see the second list has default browsers link colors

Comment: I no longer understand what are you trying to achieve. the second menu doesn't even open when i hover...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dalal/e3BHm/ when you click on "Bla Bla1" the second menue will appear in the same format of the first menu.. which I don't this to happen.. thank you for your time @Yotam Omer

Comment: Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3BHm/1/). I've changed some CSS selectors by adding `>` especially row 31: `.tabs > ul.menu > li >  a`. You have a lot of duplicated css code - try to clean up a bit. accept as answer if helped you

Comment: great.. it cleans the styles I don't want.. but why is it shown after the bordered area (where it supposed to be)? thank you so much @Yotam Omer

Comment: There are 2 blank `<p>` elements in the first tab. one before the second menu and one after..

Comment: yes I removed it and reedit the div section.. Thank you @Yotam Omer so much for your help..